# mysql database optimization ( table_cache )

Tags: mysql

Does anyone know what this means? Do i need to adjust higher than 64 or less?

After running `tunner.pl` I get this:

```
Variables to adjust:
    table_cache (> 64)
```

Comment: I wasn't able to find any references to anything called "tunner.pl" online. What is this?

Comment: mysqltuner.pl sorry typo

Answer (score 0):

You probably need more, 64 is a very low value.

Did you [read the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/table-cache.html) first?

Comment: yeah it's the syntax that is confusing me. I think it's telling me the value is to high. I'm gonna let the server run a few more days and recheck with mysqltuner to see what it says